# Open a new window using Hyperlink NavigateUrl property inside gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a grid.
Inside the grid I have a column name as `Document name`, this document contains all documents with file name `indra.pdf`.
My requirement is when I click on document name I want to open the document in a new window.
While I am saving my documents in Tables I am also saving in client side folder.

Please any can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use property:

```
target="_blank"
```

Answer (score -2):

From your statement above i can understand that u want to open your document in new window. This will help you. if not then please elaborate your question.

You can use property : target="_new"

Comment: '_new' is not a valid `target` attribute value. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp